# How can I completely start over on my computer without getting a new product code in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, windows-11, microsoft-account

I recently decided to make a new account for my computer. I want this change to be complete, as if I am getting this computer for the first time and making an email. I also want that email to be a gmail account. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Make a gmail account
2. Retrieve the product key
3. Install Windows 10 (I have Windows 11 and it was unsatisfactory) completely new
4. Setup my computer with my new gmail

In this way, I hope to pretend that my old account will not even exist. I will then make another profile for this account with my real name. I want to know:

1. Is my product key linked to my microsoft account or my computer?
2. Can I unlink my product key as if I was getting this computer from amazon?

3 (Main question). How would I go about installing a completely new windows 10 with NO links to this account using an already-used product key? This means changing the product key to a new gmail account and having no trace of this computer as it is now.

I have backed up this computer to an external hard drive. I am on Windows 11 wishing to go back to Windows 10 on a completely new computer. Is there anything I need to know in addition to the questions above?

I usually have a roundabout way of explaining things that I only notice after someone points it out, so if you wish me to clarify anything, please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my product key linked to my microsoft account or my computer?

The answer to this question is that Windows 10+ is activated with a hardware entitlement which doesn’t actually require a Microsoft Account despite Microsoft making it difficult to skip that step.

The digital entitlement is tied to your hardware, however, in the case of retail licenses in order to get the automatic activation that requires a Microsoft Account.  At the end of the day there is no specified limit to the number of Microsoft Accounts a single license can be associated with.

You shouldn’t have any problems with your idea, my only suggestion, is to perform a Reset from within Windows and choose the option to “keep nothing” by doing this you can create an account and link it to any Microsoft Account you want.

To be clear my suggestion requires creating a Microsoft Account which username is your Google account email. It is **impossible** do anything else other then that with your Google Account.  You will still have a Microsoft Account, which of course, means Outlook and OneDrive cloud services.

> Can I unlink my product key as if I was getting this computer from amazon?

Just remove the device from your Microsoft Account.  How you do this is documented by Microsoft on their website.

> How would I go about installing a completely new windows 10 with NO links to this account using an already-used product key? This means changing the product key to a new gmail account and having no trace of this computer as it is now.

You can use one of three methods:

1. Reset Windows and choose the “keep nothing” option.  This will allow you to reinstall Windows and linked a local Windows account to your new Microsoft Account.
2. Run setup.exe after you mount the current Windows 10 21H2 ISO from within Windows and select the “keep nothing” option. You will be able to create a local account and link your new Microsoft Account to it.
3. Boot to an installation media for Windows 10 21H2 and reinstall Windows after you format your HDD.  You will be able to create a local account and link your new Microsoft Account to it.

Comment: How you do something within a Microsoft Account in my opinion isn’t within scope.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am on Windows 11, does that change anything for going back to Windows 10? Or can I just download the Windows 10 installer and when installing click "Keep nothing" - is that an option?

Comment: Your question says you have Windows 10 installed.  You can install Winows 10 while within Windows 11.  My answer addresses all your concerns listed in the question.

Comment: My question says I would like to install Windows 10, not that I have it installed.

Comment: My answer doesn’t change, it currently answers, your question completely